# Minimizing the percentage share of two variables.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, statistics

This is a question that is somewhat inclined more towards statistics rather than mathematics, but because we can't consider it to be of a pure statistical nature, I believe this is the right place to ask this question.

In the city of New York, there are only four kinds of kinds of cars namely **Alpha, Beta, Gamma, Omega.**

The following table gives the individual percentage increment in the number of cars from $2017$ to $2018$. 
$$ 
\begin{array}{cc}
  \text{Alpha}& 8.88\text%\\
  \text{Beta}&9.96\text%\\
  \text{Gamma}& 12.44\text%\\
\text{Omega}& 11.68 \text%\\
\end{array}
 $$

It is also know that in the year $2017$ none of the four varieties of cars had a share less than one-sixth of the market share.
Further we are also told that the overall percentage increase in the number of cars in New York from $2017$ to $2018$ is exactly $11\text%$. We are asked to **find the minimum possible percentage share of Gamma and Omega vehicles in $2017$**

I first calculated the maximum increment possible for the city and that came out to be around $11.29\text%$ Also we can see that we can't afford to have much of Alpha and Beta types to reach the desired $11 \text%$ Someone we need to tweak the $11.29\text%$ figure by making more of Omega. But I can't find any intuitive way to get through that. Also making equation would lead to a four variable single equation which will also prove difficult to tackle. Kindly help me getting through this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic constrained optimization problem.  Imagine there is $1$ car in $2017$ as the car population will divide out.  Let $a,b,g,w$ be the fraction of a car that each kind  represents.  You have constraints $a,b,g,w \ge \frac 16$.  There are $1.11$ cars in $2018$.  You can write a linear equation to reflect that the increases must add to $0.11$.  You want to minimize $1.1244g+1.1168w$ subject to the constraints.

Comment: What you wrote seems to me to be just a restatement of the question. I wrote the linear equation and wasn't able to tackle all the four variables to minimize the required figure and that's why I had to ask it here.

Comment: There are standard methods for solving these problems.  I don't know them but have a sense how they work.  You have a simplex in four dimensional space where each constraint makes a face and the optimum is at one of the corners.  I would guess that you want $g=\frac 16$ because it grows more than $w$.